# Azure DevOps project missing in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, azureportal

If Azure DevOps project is created from Azure portal it appears both in Azure portal (portal.azure.com) in resource list and in Azure DevOps site (dev.azure.com)
But if project is created from DevOps site, it is missing in portal resources. 
Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/ You should use Microsoft support resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is ***by designed*** and is not a bug. There is ***no way to fix it*** at present.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Comment: That is pretty inconvenient :(